# Exporting all the attributes from Azure AD B2C into a csv

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-powershell, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to export AAD users from ADB2C to a csv file. I'm able to achieve this using the graph API "graph.windows.net" and some filter conditions. But with this approach, I can only get a limit of 999 records per response and I need to get the next link to do another API call and so on...

This process is taking a long time to fetch the AAD users. Hence I tried using Power shell scripts i.e using Get-AzureADUser, using this approach I was able to get all the users within a short duration. But the issue in this approach I'm not able to get all the attributes that I get via the rest call (i.e the attribute is userIdentites).

The reason I'm looking for userIdentites is, that I can filter out the users with social logins like gmail.com or facebook.com

How can I achieve this using PowerShell scripts? or using CLI or Python?

A sample response from the Graph API -
[image: Response from the Graph API]

Powershell script to get the same attributes, but I'm getting blank userIdentites, which is wrong. Expected is few users are to get social logins as shows in Graph API Response

```
For($i=$index; $i -lt $regexArray.Length; $i++){
    
    $regexArray[$i] | Out-File $tempLogFile -NoNewline
    $blobFileName = $fileName + $i + ".csv"
    
    Write-Output ("Exporting Users Information in a CSV File for Surname with Regex : " + $regexArray[$i])
    Get-AzureADUser -All $true | where-Object { $_.Surname -cmatch $regexArray[$i]} | 
        select otherMails,DisplayName,userIdentites,UserPrincipalName,Department | Export-Csv $tempfilepath -NoTypeInformation

    Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Context $context -Container $container -File $tempfilepath -Blob $blobFileName -Force
    Write-Output ("Exported File Name : " + $blobFileName)

    Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Context $context -Container $container -File $tempLogFile -Blob $logFile -Force
    Write-Output ("Exporting completed for Surname with Regex : " + $regexArray[$i])   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static async Task ListUsers(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Getting list of users...");

        try
        {
            // Get all users
            var users = await graphClient.Users
                .Request()
                .Select(e => new
                {
                    e.DisplayName,
                    e.Id,
                    e.Identities
                })
                .GetAsync();

            // Iterate over all the users in the directory
            var pageIterator = PageIterator<User>
                .CreatePageIterator(
                    graphClient,
                    users,
                    // Callback executed for each user in the collection
                    (user) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(user));
                        return true;
                    },
                    // Used to configure subsequent page requests
                    (req) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Reading next page of users...");
                        return req;
                    }
                );

            await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management/manage-b2c-users-dotnet-core-ms-graph/